# Calculate coordinates of a point on a circular arc

Tags: geometry, circles

I have following dilemma I need to solve for my software:

I have a circular arc, and I do know these:

- x,y coordinates of startpoint of the arc
- x,y coordinates of endpoint of the arc
- x,y coordinates of the center of the arc
- The arc is drawn clockwise between startpoint and endpoint, while the last point is the middlepoint of the rotation.

What I would need is a way to calculate the coordinates of a point on the arch by knowing only the arc distance (not linear distance) from the startpoint. For example lets say the arc is in total 25 mm long, I would like to know the coordinates of a point being 11.5mm arc distance from the startpoint.

Comment: It rather depends on the [shape of the arch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arch#Types_of_arches).  Does your question mean it is the arc of a circle?

Comment: yes its the arch of a circle

Comment: First, find the center of the circle. Then, find the radius of the circle. Then, use the relation $s=r\theta$ that holds among the arc length $s$, the radius $r$, and the angle subtended by an arc at the center of the circle ($\theta$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your given points are $A,B,M$ with $M$ the midpoint of the arc.

1. Find the angle between vectors $MA$ and $MB$, using dot product: 
   $$\alpha = \cos^{-1}\frac{MA\cdot MB }{|MA|\ |MB|}$$
2. Find the radius $R$ of the circle; trigonometry gives
   $$R=\frac12 |MA| \sec\frac\alpha2$$
3. Find the center $C$ of the circle by going from $M$ in the direction toward $(A+B)/2$ by distance $R$. That is,
   $$C = M+ R\,\frac{(A+B)/2-M}{|(A+B)/2-M|}$$
4. The required angle of rotation is $\theta=l/R$ where $l$ is the arc distance.
5. Apply the rotation matrix by $\theta$ to vector $CA$ and add the result to $C$. 
   $$
   X = C + \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta& \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix} CA $$

The point $X$ is what you are looking for.

Comment: not really sure i understood point 1 and 2... as far as i understand |MA| = |MB| = R, or is that wrong?